# soliton solutions to PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soliton-theory

so I'm doing an advanced course on PDEs and one of the topics we covered was soliton solutions to the KdV equation. We consider it in this form

$$u_t + uu_x + u_{xxx} = 0$$

And my lecturer said that there exists an exact 2-soliton formula which has some sort of log term in it but I don't know.

My quesiton is- does there exist a 3-soliton solution of the same class?

Comment: Can you recall what is a soliton solution in this case?

Comment: u = 2κ^2sech^2 κ(x − 4κ^2t).

Comment: No I meant the definition of a soliton. I guess there could be translating and scaling ones but I am not sure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the results are in _Solitons: An Introduction_ by Drazin & Johnson.

Comment: There are explicitly known $n$-soliton solutions for any $n$, as is very well-known. Just search the web for “KdV n-soliton”.